# Is windows.h Sleep(int) function wasteful?

Tags: c++, windows

I am now trying to write a program that waits two minutes and 25 seconds in C++. I use the Sleep function of  like that:

`Sleep(145000);`

Now, my laptop heats up every time I run this function, and the fan starts working.

Now to the question - is this function known for being wasteful? Should I even use it? do I have a better option?

Comment: no, `Sleep` not "wasteful". issue in something else

Comment: `Sleep()` simply causes the current thread to release its time slice to the system scheduler, and the system scheduler then allocates time to other processes.   If doing that causes "wastage" it is a sign that the operating system is allowing ANOTHER process to run that consumes more resources.   The problem is therefore in the other process.

Answer (score 6):

The Windows Sleep() function puts the current thread to sleep. It doesn't run a busy-waiting while-loop or anything like that, it just re-schedules the thread to start up again after the sleep period specified as the function parameter. If your fan is starting up, I suggest looking at the currently running processes using Task Manager.